# SQL compare the same columns from two different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple table called (req_table) that contains (id) column, (stat_id) column and 5 columns (prev_1, prev_2, prev_3, prev_4, prev_5,) these 5 columns are duplicated in another table called (admins_table).

I want to get (id) column where (stat_id) column not equal 3 and the 5 columns in (req_table) (prev_1, prev_2, prev_3, prev_4, prev_5,) are equal to the same columns in (admins_table)

I got the correct result for the (stat_id) column but it get wrong result for(prev_1, prev_2, prev_3, prev_4, prev_5,) columns,

for example my code show the result of column(id) where (prev_3) column in (req_table) = 1 and in (admins_table) = 0

but it shouldn't show this column(id) because they have different value.

here is my code:

```
SELECT distinct id, stat_id, prev_1, prev_2, prev_3, prev_4, prev_5,

FROM req_table

where stat_id not in (3)

or id in ( SELECT  req_table.req_id FROM admins_table inner join req_table on admins_table.[prev_1] = req_table.[prev_1] and admins_table.[prev_1] = 1 and admins_table.admin_name  = 'admin3' and req_table.stat_id not in (3)) 
or id in ( SELECT  req_table.req_id FROM admins_table inner join req_table on admins_table.[prev_2] = req_table.[prev_2] and admins_table.[prev_2] = 1 and admins_table.admin_name  = 'admin3' and req_table.stat_id not in (3)) 
or id in ( SELECT  req_table.req_id FROM admins_table inner join req_table on admins_table.[prev_3] = req_table.[prev_3] and admins_table.[prev_3] = 1 and admins_table.admin_name  = 'admin3' and req_table.stat_id not in (3))  
or id in ( SELECT  req_table.req_id FROM admins_table inner join req_table on admins_table.[prev_4] = req_table.[prev_4] and admins_table.[prev_4] = 1 and admins_table.admin_name  = 'admin3' and req_table.stat_id not in (3))  
or id in ( SELECT  req_table.req_id FROM admins_table inner join req_table on admins_table.[prev_5] = req_table.[prev_5] and admins_table.[prev_5] = 1 and admins_table.admin_name  = 'admin3' and req_table.stat_id not in (3))
```

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: 1) Simplify! 2) Show us some sample table data _and the expected result_, all as formatted text (no images.) [mcve]

Comment: And show your table structure as DDL rather than paragraph text - too hard to make sense of.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is always a red flag...

Comment: @jarlh  I added an image to make the question clearer

Comment: It still is completely unclear to me.

Comment: @wildplasser in my code I added a condition where admin_name = admin3 so the id column that should be displayed is the one where prev_1 = 1 and  prev_2 = 1 because the column admin3 has prev_1 = 1 and  prev_2 = 1

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you logic correctly, you want `exists()` :
(I am not sure about the *intended* AND/OR logic ...)

---

```
SELECT id, stat_id, prev_1, prev_2, prev_3, prev_4, prev_5
FROM req_table rt
WHERE stat_id not in (3)
AND EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM admins_table at
        WHERE at.stat_id NOT IN(3)
        AND at.req_id = rt.id
        AND at.admin_name  = 'admin3'
        AND at.prev_1 = rt.prev_1
        AND at.prev_2 = rt.prev_2
        AND at.prev_3 = rt.prev_3
        AND at.prev_4 = rt.prev_4
        AND at.prev_5 = rt.prev_5
        )
        ;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer I tried the code but it shows nothing, I added an image to make the question clearer

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by using and instead of or in the first condition

```
SELECT distinct id, stat_id, prev_1, prev_2, prev_3, prev_4, prev_5,

FROM req_table

where stat_id not in (3)

and id in ( SELECT  req_table.req_id FROM admins_table inner join req_table on admins_table.[prev_1] = req_table.[prev_1] and admins_table.[prev_1] = 1 and admins_table.admin_name  = 'admin3' and req_table.stat_id not in (3)) 
or id in ( SELECT  req_table.req_id FROM admins_table inner join req_table on admins_table.[prev_2] = req_table.[prev_2] and admins_table.[prev_2] = 1 and admins_table.admin_name  = 'admin3' and req_table.stat_id not in (3)) 
or id in ( SELECT  req_table.req_id FROM admins_table inner join req_table on admins_table.[prev_3] = req_table.[prev_3] and admins_table.[prev_3] = 1 and admins_table.admin_name  = 'admin3' and req_table.stat_id not in (3))  
or id in ( SELECT  req_table.req_id FROM admins_table inner join req_table on admins_table.[prev_4] = req_table.[prev_4] and admins_table.[prev_4] = 1 and admins_table.admin_name  = 'admin3' and req_table.stat_id not in (3))  
or id in ( SELECT  req_table.req_id FROM admins_table inner join req_table on admins_table.[prev_5] = req_table.[prev_5] and admins_table.[prev_5] = 1 and admins_table.admin_name  = 'admin3' and req_table.stat_id not in (3))
```

Comment: Beware of the precedence of `AND` vs `OR`

Answer (score 0):

My offer is to handle null as well.
[NULL complexities – Part 1 - by Itzik Ben-Gan](https://sqlperformance.com/2019/12/t-sql-queries/null-complexities-part-1)!

This is the code that I was using:

```
USE tempdb;
go
create table req_table(id int not null, stat_id int not null, req_id int not null, prev_1 int, prev_2 int, prev_3 int, prev_4 int, prev_5 int);
create table admins_table(id int not null, prev_1 int, prev_2 int, prev_3 int, prev_4 int, prev_5 int, admin_name varchar(20) not null);
go
insert req_table
values  (1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5),
        (2,3,2,1,2,3,4,5),
        (3,1,3,1,2,3,4,5),
        (4,3,4,null,2,3,4,5),
        (5,1,5,null,null,null,null,null),
        (6,3,6,null,1,1,1,1);
insert admins_table
values  (1,1,2,3,4,5,'admin3'),
        (2,1,2,3,4,5,'admin3'),
        (3,1,2,3,4,5,'admin3'),
        (4,null,2,3,4,5,'admin3'),
        (5,null,null,null,null,null,'admin3'),
        (6,null,1,1,1,1,'admin3');
go 
--Your Query
SELECT distinct id, stat_id, prev_1, prev_2, prev_3, prev_4, prev_5
FROM req_table
where stat_id not in (3)
or id in ( SELECT  req_table.req_id FROM admins_table inner join req_table on admins_table.[prev_1] = req_table.[prev_1] and admins_table.[prev_1] = 1 and admins_table.admin_name  = 'admin3' and req_table.stat_id not in (3)) 
or id in ( SELECT  req_table.req_id FROM admins_table inner join req_table on admins_table.[prev_2] = req_table.[prev_2] and admins_table.[prev_2] = 1 and admins_table.admin_name  = 'admin3' and req_table.stat_id not in (3)) 
or id in ( SELECT  req_table.req_id FROM admins_table inner join req_table on admins_table.[prev_3] = req_table.[prev_3] and admins_table.[prev_3] = 1 and admins_table.admin_name  = 'admin3' and req_table.stat_id not in (3))  
or id in ( SELECT  req_table.req_id FROM admins_table inner join req_table on admins_table.[prev_4] = req_table.[prev_4] and admins_table.[prev_4] = 1 and admins_table.admin_name  = 'admin3' and req_table.stat_id not in (3))  
or id in ( SELECT  req_table.req_id FROM admins_table inner join req_table on admins_table.[prev_5] = req_table.[prev_5] and admins_table.[prev_5] = 1 and admins_table.admin_name  = 'admin3' and req_table.stat_id not in (3))
go
--My offer
select  id, stat_id, prev_1, prev_2, prev_3, prev_4, prev_5
from    req_table r
where   stat_id != 3
        AND EXISTS (select r.prev_1, r.prev_2, r.prev_3, r.prev_4, r.prev_5
            INTERSECT
            select a.prev_1, a.prev_2, a.prev_3, a.prev_4, a.prev_5 from admins_table a where a.admin_name  = 'admin3');
go
drop table req_table,admins_table;
```

[image]